# Heroku aborts rake:precompile when it requires database access

Tags: database, postgresql, deployment, heroku

Some of the project assets are ERBs (like `file.js.coffee.erb`) that will pull data from the database as to write themselves up. Database tables seems to be created ok, but Heroku keeps halting at the precompile with an error like this:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Well, ok. I searched in Heroku Devcenter for help and found [an article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#assetsprecompile-failures) that explained this was actually happening due to the lack of config vars in the environment. So the instruction was to run:

```
env RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=scheme://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname bundle exec rake assets:precompile 2>&1
```

So I run the command with the proper replacements, from the Heroku's tollbelt *(heroku run ...)*, putting `postgresql` as the `scheme`, also filling `user`, `pass`, and `dbname` fields properly. An then, again:

```
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

  (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/file.js.coffee.erb)/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize'
```

Seems like I was suposed to use some real info from Heroku's automated database configurations, but I just have no idea what are those configurations.

I'm kinda stuck with that. Anyone could lend a hand?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Well, I managed around that by setting up a production environment locally, precompiling and just then pushing it to Heroku. So far so good.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this by enabling user-env-compile:

- [Heroku Labs: user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile)

It's generally discouraged but kind of needed in your situation.